# error code 1064 when i try to use greater than for aggregate

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    (SELECT discount_percent
    FROM products
    WHERE discount_percent > AVG(discount_percent)
```

I'm not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: Your parentheses aren't balanced.

Comment: The subquery should just be `(SELECT AVG(discount_percent) FROM products)`

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE discount_percent >
    (SELECT discount_percent
    FROM products
    WHERE discount_percent > AVG(discount_percent)
```

should be:

```
WHERE discount_percent > (SELECT AVG(discount_percent) FROM products)
```

You're missing a closing parenthesis after the subquery. But a bigger problem is that you can't use an aggregation function in the `WHERE` clause, because aggregation is done *after* selecting the rows. Also, you need to make the query return just one result so it can be compared with `>`.

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE discount_percent > AVG(discount_percent)` 
probably needs to be changed to 
`HAVING discount_percent > AVG(discount_percent)`

The `HAVING` clause is used to filter on aggregate functions, such as the `AVG` you are calling.

For some more documentation on this, check out this link: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx